# Determining 4 consecutive numbers from a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have a problem and i do not know how to solve it. 
i have to find a formula in excel or code in vba to highlights the 4 consecutive numbers from a cell B2.
In this cell are 20 numbers (from 1 to 90).

Comment: What character separates the numbers ??

Comment: comma separates the numbers

Comment: are they like so 1,2,3,4 or 1,87,65,2,56,3,22,4 as in consecutives are there, but not in order?

Comment: You must build an array, using Split function for your separator ",". Please, see my answer... It will sow the four existing numbers.

Comment: numbers are extracted randomly and i have to highlights only the 4 consecutive.

Comment: i wanted to attach a picture, but they did not let me :)

Comment: like these :11, 15, 16, 23, 29, 30, 31, 38, 41, 47, 49, 59, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 78, 79

Comment: when you say "consecutive" what does that mean? Don't you need the first existing numbers? Do you need to filter those numbers and e extract the first consecutive ones?

Comment: no, i have to find out a group with 4 consecutive numbers, no matter what numbers. that is the only condition

Comment: Which numbers would be highlighted from the example you posted in comments above? In order to highlight numbers within a cell (a part of a string), you'll need to ensure the cell contents is a string, and not the result of a formula, and you will need to write VBA code to do that.  I suggest you edit your question with the code you have tried, and where/if you have run into problems with it.

Comment: Then, try my answer code. It inputs an array with all numbers separated by ",", then sort the obtained array and finds the four consecutive numbers. My understanding about your request was that you need first four consecutive values. Meaning that the first one is less with a unit then the following one. Is that correct? I did not check if the analyzed cell is empty, if its value is a string, if the string contains comma separators and the elements of the obtained array are numbers. I've just try to give you a solution logic... If no consecutive numbers found, it sends a relevant message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tray this code, please:

```
Sub testSplitExtract()
  Dim c As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long, boolFound As Boolean
    Set c =  Range("B2")
    arr = Split(c.Value, ",") 'obtain the values array
    arraySort arr             'sort the obtained array
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 3
        If CLng(arr(i)) = CLng(arr(i + 1)) - 1 And _
                CLng(arr(i + 1)) = CLng(arr(i + 2)) - 1 And _
                    CLng(arr(i + 2)) = CLng(arr(i + 3)) - 1 Then
            Debug.Print arr(i), arr(i + 1), arr(i + 2), arr(i + 3)
            MsgBox arr(i) & "," & arr(i + 1) & "," & arr(i + 2) & "," & arr(i + 3)
            boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not boolFound Then MsgBox "No four consecutive numbers in the analized cell"
End Sub

Private Function arraySort(ByRef arrS As Variant) ' function to sort the array
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, str1 As Variant, str2 As Variant
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrS)
       For j = i To UBound(arrS)
            If arrS(j) < arrS(i) Then
                str1 = arrS(i)
                str2 = arrS(j)
                arrS(i) = str2
                arrS(j) = str1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Why would you want to sort the array, would that put non consecutives in consecutive order, does the OP not mean 4 consecutive one after the other?  Also, check the typo in your not found :)

Comment: I am afraid he does'n need the existing four consecutive numbers of the array. He wants (at least this is what I understood), first four consecutive values, in sense that first one must be lower then the following one with one unit. Otherwise, first number of the array are consecutive in the sense that each of them follows the precedent... Am I wrong? In fact, it is his turn to better clarify what he meant... Now, I also started to ask myself if this is what he meant... Otherwise, why to mention "consecutive" and not only first four? :)

Comment: I see, i read it as first four consecutive as in the string so "1,5,4,2,3,4,5,6,10,11" would return 2,3,4,5 not 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: According to his way of asking, I can admit that also your understanding can stand. But, the array must also be sorted and it would only be need **to return the first four sorted elements**. In such a case the code looking for consecutive values has to just be eliminated. Like I said, now it's his turn to explain what he really needs... I  initially posted my answer to return the four sorted array elements. After that I read again what he said and adapted the code according to my new understanding... Which I must confess I am not so sure it is the correct one. He must clarify that

Comment: works fine! thank you!

Comment: @Brutus: Welcome! Glad to help. I was not completely sure that I exactly understood what you meant by "consecutive numbers"...

Comment: i am doing some statistics about the consecutive numbers extracted to a lottery, and this help me to understand what are the most often extracted 4 consecutive numbers. the algoritm i have to extend to all 25 rows that i will analyze weekly

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so as discussed above

```
Function CONSECUTIVE_NUMBERS(strInput As String) As Boolean

Dim a() As String
Dim l As Long

a = Split(strInput, ",")

For l = 0 To UBound(a) - 3

        If (Trim(a(l + 1)) - Trim(a(l)) = 1) And _
            (Trim(a(l + 2)) - Trim(a(l + 1)) = 1) And _
            (Trim(a(l + 3)) - Trim(a(l + 2)) = 1) Then
            CONSECUTIVE_NUMBERS = True
            Exit For
        End If

Next l

End Function
```

or changing the IF to be

```
If (Trim(a(l + 1)) - Trim(a(l)) = 1) And _
            (Trim(a(l + 2)) - Trim(a(l + 1)) = 1) And _
            (Trim(a(l + 3)) - Trim(a(l + 2)) = 1) Then
            CONSECUTIVE_NUMBERS = Trim(a(l)) & "," & _
                                    Trim(a(l + 1)) & "," & _
                                    Trim(a(l + 2)) & "," & _
                                    Trim(a(l + 3))
            Exit For
        End If
```

and having the a string return from the function to output the 4

Answer (score 1):

```
Function ConsecutiveFour(myNumbers)
Dim Num, Result
Num = Split(myNumbers, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(Num) - 3
    If WorksheetFunction.And(Num(i + 1) - Num(i) = 1, Num(i + 2) - Num(i + 1) = 1, Num(i + 3) - Num(i + 2) = 1) = True Then
    Result = Result & "," & "[" & Num(i) & "," & Num(i + 1) & "," & Num(i + 2) & "," & Num(i + 3) & "]"
    End If
Next

ConsecutiveFour = Right(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

[image]